# Using <router-outlet> with md-tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a navbar that uses Angular 2's Material design . I have came across multiple solutions to get it to work. But what I am trying to accomplish is: Whenever I try these other solutions, the "Material Animation" doesn't work anymore.
So I have tried to implement a fix to this but my router outlet keeps getting in the way because I need to check if people are authenticated.
I have 2 paths /register and /login that need to be outside of the main app container, then inside the main app container I have a md-tab navbar component, with the content being entire components. I can't quite figure out how to seperate /register and /login from the navbar and it's "children"

navbar.html:

```
    <md-tab-group>
      <md-tab label="Profile"><profile></profile></md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Notification"><notification></notification></md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Home"><home></home></md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Create a Card"><create-Post></create-Post></md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Logout"></md-tab>
      Current Area:
      Fun  &nbsp;<md-slide-toggle
    class="example-margin"
    [color]="color"
    [checked]="checked"
    (change)="onChange($event)">Information</md-slide-toggle>

    </md-tab-group>
```

app.routing:

```
    ﻿import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/index';
    import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/index';
    import { CreatePostComponent } from './createPost/index';
    import { UserPostsComponent } from './userposts/index';
    import { RegisterComponent } from './register/index';
    import { NotificationComponent } from './notification/index';
    import { NavBarComponent } from './navBar/index';
    import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
        { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
          { path: '', component: NavBarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'post', component: CreatePostComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'cards', component: UserPostsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
        // otherwise redirect to home
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ];

    export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app.component.html:

```
<!-- main app container -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```